# Get Value from Array as Array Key

Tags: php, arrays, key

How do I recursively get value from array where I need to explode a key?
I know, it's not good the question, let me explain.

I got an array

```
[
  "abc" => "def", 
  "hij" => [
              "klm" => "nop", 
              "qrs" => [
                          "tuv" => "wxy"
                       ]
           ]
]
```

So, inside a function, I pass:

```
function xget($section) {
    return $this->yarray["hij"][$section];
}
```

But when I want to get `tuv` value with this function, I want to make section as array, example:

To get `hij.klm` value (`nop`), I would do `xget('klm')`, but to get `hij.klm.qrs.tuv`, I can't do `xget(['qrs', 'tuv'])`, because PHP consider `$section` as key, and does not recursively explode it. There's any way to do it without using some `if`s and `$section[$i]` ?

Comment: You will have to manually traverse the array to do this

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen what do you mean with "manually traverse" ?
I would just need to do like `$this->yarray["hij"]$section`, but PHP does not allow

Comment: where are we on this question ? If you received an answer please mark it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function xget($section) {
    return $this->yarray["hij"][$section];
}
```

that one is static function right?

you can do that also for this

```
function xget($section) {
    if(isset($this->yarray["hij"][$section])){
         return $this->yarray["hij"][$section];
    }elseif(isset($this->yarray["hij"]["klm"]["qrs"][$section])){
         return $this->yarray["hij"]["klm"]["qrs"][$section];
    }
}
```

as long as the key name between two of them are not the same.

Comment: Yeah, but what should I do if I don't know the key names and the count? It was supposed to be dynamic to the count  and key names, so I can use it with another multidimensional or unidimensional array.

Comment: you should do recursive function for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [array_walk_recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk-recursive.php) to find `tuv`'s value regardless of the nested structure:

```
$tuv_val='';
function find_tuv($k,$v)
{
   global $tuv_val;
   if ($k=='tuv')
      $tuv_val=$v;
}
array_walk_recursive($this->yarray,"find_tuv");
echo "the value of 'tuv' is $tuv_val";
```

Answer (score 0):

try my code

```
<?php

    $array = array(
            'aaa' => 'zxc',
            'bbb' => 'asd',
            'ccc' => array(
                    'ddd' => 'qwe',
                    'eee' => 'tyu',
                    'fff' => array(
                                'ggg' => 'uio',
                                'hhh' => 'hjk',
                                'iii' => 'bnm',
                            ),
                ),
        );

    $find = '';

    function xget($key){
        $GLOBALS['find'] = $key;
        $find = $key;
        array_walk_recursive($GLOBALS['array'],'walkingRecursive');
    }


    function walkingRecursive($value, $key)
    {
        if ($key==$GLOBALS['find']){
            echo $value;
        }
    }


    xget('ggg');
?>
```